# Why does this youtube embed code stop working if I remove the embed tag?

Tags: html, flash, browser, youtube, youtube-api

I understood that the embed code had an embed tag inside the object tag as a fallback for IE and old browsers. But, if I, for example, take this code:

```
    <object width="400" height="336"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/_25bsKcXw5o&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/_25bsKcXw5o&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="336" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
```

And remove the embed:

```
<object width="400" height="336"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/_25bsKcXw5o&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
</object>
```

It doesnt display in Chrome or in Firefox. Why? Does this make sense to anybody? I've tried with several different videos, and the same happens with all of them.

The reason I am doing this is because I wanted to determine where should I change the youtube url attributes (to change behaviour of the player). After doing some more tests, I also noticed that Chrome is responding to he changes I do to the embed tag's parameters, and not to the object's...

Comment: why not use the newer iframe code?

Comment: Long story, but basically the youtube embeds are supplied by the users, so I cant control which version the use.

Comment: hmm how about just asking for video url and generating your own code? for existing entries you can pick out video id from submitted codes with some regex..

Comment: that wil give you complete control over the code. btw it is kind of obvious but do you make sure users cannot add bad code?

Comment: Not possible. As I said, it is a long story, basically the site I am working on pulls content from different rss sources, so I dont have complete control over the final code. Even if I had, I would like to know the answer to this...

Comment: sorryy.. i am a html5/js guy.. ;) flash/embedd goes over my head :(

Comment: I'm not sure, so I make this a comment instead of an answer, but I believe you need to have data="http://www.yout..." as an attribute of the object element for it to work in non-IE browsers. The embed tag is  not a fallback for IE but was at first for Netscape and later used by other non-IE browsers (and is valid again in HTML5, I believe), I don't know for sure which browsers that renders embed tags today, and under what circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link to Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) which explains the `OBJECT` and `EMBED` tags in detail.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. For me it said something like: OBJECT by default is using an ActiveX component to play the movie while if there is an EMBED tag that point to a flash player plugin then that's what being used. ActiveX is by the way not supported by all browsers which to me explains a little bit your problem and the different browser behaviors ...